# Sketch this body and calculate the mass of the body

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A solid body in the first octant is bounded by the planes $z = 0$, $y = 0$, $z = y$ and the
parabolic cylinder $y = 4 − x^2$, and has density $\rho = xz$.  calculate the
mass of the body.

answer

$$x: 0\to2$$

$$y: 0\to4-x^2$$

$$z: 0\to4$$

so $m$ is the triple integral of $x*z = 32$
is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The domain of integration is depicted in the figure below. The function that we have to integrate is $$f(x,y,z)=xz.$$
[image]
Given $x,y$ we have to integrate $f$ with respect to $z$ over the interval $[0,y]$:

$$\color{red}{\int_0^y}xz\ \color{red}{dz}=\frac{1}{2}xy^2.$$

Then this function will have to be integrated with respect to $y$ over the interval $[0,4-x^2]$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{\int_0^{4-x^2}}xy^2\ \color{blue}{dy}=\frac{1}{6}x(4-x^2)^3=\frac{1}{6}(-x^7+12x^5-48x^3+64x).$$

Finally, this function of $x$ will have to be integrated over the interval $[0,2]:$

$$\frac{1}{6}\int_0^2(-x^7+12x^5-48x^3+64x)dx=$$
$$\frac{1}{6}\left(-\frac{1}{8}2^8+2\cdot2^6-12\cdot2^4+32\cdot2^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\left(-32+128-192+128\right)=\frac{1}{6}(256-224)=\frac{32}{6}.$$

So, the division by $6$ was missing...